# Move To is preserving the permissions if we move the files inside the same site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, move-to

We have 2 site collections SiteA & SiteB. and inside siteA we have 2 document libraries DL1 & DL2. Inside DL1 we have folders and files with unique permissions. now if we use the MoveTo option to move the folders from DL1 to DL2 the folders' & files' permissions will be preserved which is great. but if we move the folders from SiteA to SiteB then the folders' & files' permissions will be lost. so can anyone advice why this is happening? and is there a way to preserve the permissions when moving folders and files across sites?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably losing permissions because user Ids and groups are different between site collections. Losing the permissions is possibly a design decision I would say.
I don't know of an out-of-the-box way to move items between site collections, but this seems something you could achieve with a custom solution.